# Ubuntu 16.04 install php5.3

Tags: php-5.3, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I need to install php5.3 in my ubuntu 16.04 but I want to keep if it's possible the php7.0 versión so I could change versions if i need it.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way to do this is to use Vagrant. When I say "best" I mean, most maintainable over time and that allows you to keep your current setup.

- Install Vagrant
- Install VirtualBox
- Find a suitable box on the hashicorp site
- Create your Vagrant file
- Run `vagrant up`

Alternatively, you can build your own box without pushing it to, or needing to pull from, hashicorp. See the excellent "Packer" project which allows you to define your box using JSON: https://www.packer.io/intro/index.html

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it

Answer (score 0):

There are Github projects phpbrew or phpenv.But it's really hard to make them work

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yeah, Vagrant or Docker still might help you, as well as VirtualBox (or something like it)